# Cross ratio on sphere

Tags: projective-geometry, cross-product, riemann-sphere

Project from the north pole to have an identification of the sphere in real space $\mathbb{R}^3$ and the complex projective line. Given $4$ (say, different) points on the sphere, I can project and then compute their cross-ratio.

Where can I find a formula that directly computes this value from the four vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$ in terms of cross product, scalar product etc?

Answer (score 1):

Identify the sphere $S^2 \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ with the space of imaginary quaternions of norm $1$. Then an explicit expression for the cross-ratio can be found in the arXiv preprint *[On a Quaternionic Analogue of the Cross-Ratio](https://arxiv.org/abs/1112.0612)*, see in particular Section 3.